# Derived Column FindString Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, derived

I have a dataset as below

```
S.No Column_A                         Column_B

1    San Diego Sewage Department      Hello
2    California Sewage Plant          Hi
3    Paulo Alto Sewage                YOLO
```

Now I need to find and replace Sewage Department, Sewage Plant, Sewage to SD

So final result should look like

```
S.No Column_A                         Column_B

1    San Diego SD                     Hello
2    California SD                    Hi
3    Paulo Alto SD                    YOLO
```

I have tried writing like this in derived column but not all of them are getting converted

```
FINDSTRING(Column_A,"Sewage%",1)>0 ? REPLACE(Column_A,"Sewage%","") + "SD" : Column_A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are using the SQL wild card in your functions, and as far as I know they don't accept wild cards.

I think the following will be equivalent:

```
FINDSTRING(Column_A,"Sewage",1) > 0 ? 
    SUBSTRING(Column_A, 1, FINDSTRING(Column_A,"Sewage",1) - 1) + "SD" : 
    Column_A
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I am getting the final result in Column_A as San Diego SSD, California SSD, Paulo Alto SSD, Can you let me know where exactly is the error with

Comment: I have edited the answer, it just had the wrong length in the substring function.

Answer (score 0):

How about running the following three queries.  You would have to make sure the last one is ran last:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET column_A = REPLACE(column_A, 'Sewage Department', 'SD')

UPDATE MyTable
SET column_A = REPLACE(column_A, 'Sewage Plant', 'SD')

UPDATE MyTable
SET column_A = REPLACE(column_A, 'Sewage', 'SD')
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I have to use Derived Column